Get all symbol that are implicitly declared in a compilation
I'm trying to get all symbol inside Compilation. To do that, i need to get both symbol that are explicitly declared and symbol that are implicitly declared.
I can get all symbol that are explicitly declared by looping syntax tree. However, i don't know how to obtain all symbol that are implicitly declared because i can't get them from syntax tree.
So, how do i get all symbol that are implicitly declared in a compilation ?
Also, is there any better way to get all symbol than this ?
In the documentation, in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.imodulesymbol.globalnamespace , it was said that the global (root) namespace symbol can be used to browse all of the symbols defined in the module. If that is true, then i can use it to get all symbol in a compilation by looping all module symbol inside each assembly symbol. However, i don't know how to get all symbol from the global namespace symbol.
